# Eval on clone object changes values of parent object

Tags: javascript

This is a part of a large function, but to put it simply:

```
var round1 = {gg: "wp"};
var round2 = round1;
eval('round2.gg="bp"')
```

This gives:

```
   round2 == {gg: 'bp'}
```

But also changes:

```
  round1 == {gg: 'bp'}
```

How to get around this ?

***Edit: why I need eval ?***

As a part of my function, i have the paths of the bigobject recorded as strings in an array, such that i can use eval to change the value of a specific property and copy it in a cloned object.

Example:

```
var bigobject = {
  a: { x: "1", y: "2" },
  //b: similar
}
var pathobject [".a.x",".a.y",".b.x",".b.y"]


// This eval is run in loop, so i = index of loop. but lets say i=0
var temp_object = bigobject;
var i=0;
eval('temp_object' + pathobject[i] + '=' + '5');
```

Comment: Please provide enough code to show why an eval is at all needed here. You need to clone the object and then just do `round2["gg"]="bp"`

Comment: hi, i have edited the question, please look.

Comment: `const [,n,m]=pathobject[i].split("."); temp_object[n][m]=5` - no need for eval

Comment: I can't do temp_object[n][m] directly because [n][m] is generated from loop, thats why i eval [n][m] which is basically a string.

Comment: I generate n and m from ".a.x" from the loop, so n="a" and m="x" -